# Insertar en elemento <a> referencia url con valor de variable en Resource.resx

Tags: c#, asp.net

En mi proyecto tengo un archivo **Resource.resx** dentro de la carpeta **App_GlobalResources.**

En el archivo **Resource.resx** tengo un nombre de variable que llamo ***url1*** con el valor de una ruta como: ***/Ruta1/pdf/mi.pdf***

En el archivo **.aspx** tengo el siguiente código:

```
<a class="clase1" href=@Strings.url1>Ver</a>
```

En teoría al pulsar el enlace tendría que ir a la ruta que tiene la variable ***url1*** pero no funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analiza la implementacion del articulo

[ASP.Net Global Resource example: How to use Resource file in ASP.Net using C# and VB.Net](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Global-Resource-example-How-to-use-Resource-file-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

En el ejemplo veras que usa `<%$ %>` si es un control de asp.net

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" Text="<%$Resources:Resource, <Resource Name> %>" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" />
```

o quizas en `html` usando

```
<span><%=Resources.Resource.<Resource Name> %></span>
```

Quizas en tu caso debeas intentar

```
<a class="clase1" href='<%=Resources.Resource.url1 %>' >Ver</a>
```

usando los `<%=  %>` defiens codigo servidor que es justamente el que accede al resource

Comment: Fantastico ! Me sirvió con <a class="clase1" href='<%=Resources.Resource.url1 %>' >Ver</a>